# Attachment not working in phpfox

Tags: jquery, phpfox

Here's an error am getting in Phpfox when i try to use the attachment feature

```
TypeError: $Core.shareInlineBox is not a function
```

i was able to retrieve this error from the Firefox web console but i don't seem to have any solution to it.

Here's the attachment link's code

```
<a href="#" onclick="return $Core.shareInlineBox(this, 'js_form_mail', true, 'attachment.add', 500, '&amp;category_id=mail');" class="js_hover_title"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/phpfox/upload/theme/frontend/default/style/default/image/misc/application_add.png" alt="" class="v_middle"><span class="js_hover_info">Attach a File</span></a>
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check that `share.js` located in static jscprit folder of attachment module is added or not. If not then please include it in header.